# FFT implementation using Apache Common Math

Tags: java, fft, imagej

I am trying to implement the FFT in ImageJ and I tried the this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291896/fft-image-is-not-the-same-as-the-fft-image-produced-in-imagej

but I could seem to make it work so I thought I would try using Apache Common Math and see what it produces. I have tried the following lines of code but I keep getting an error when I try to do the f. transform(). What am I missing?

```
FastFourierTransformer f = new FastFourierTransformer(null);
TransformType type;
f.transform(fdata, type.GENERAL);
```

This is the error I get:

The method transform(double[], org.apache.commons.math3.transform.TransformType) in the type FastFourierTransformer is not applicable for the arguments (double[], org.apache.batik.ext.awt.g2d.TransformType)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selena, you appear to have a namespace collision.  If you need both the Apache Commons bundle and the org.apache.batik.ext.awt.g2d bundle, you may have to try qualifying the variable declaration like this:

```
org.apache.commons.math3.transform.TransformType type;
```

What are you importing in this code file?

Comment: So when the fastfouriertransformer returns a Complex[] how would I make that into a float array because I need to pass the ImageJ powerSpectrum and it only takes floats. I am importing this code file because I wanted to be able to see the code. I wanted to write the fft by hand but its not producing the correct pictures and I don't know why.

Comment: I don't know imageJ, but would it help you to use Complex.getReal() and Complex.getImaginary()?